# UWP app starts on startup when compiled with .net native

Tags: uwp, .net-native

My UWP app crashes on startup with the following exception when built with .net native (debug or release):

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.MissingMetadataException' in System.Private.Interop.dll
Windows.Foundation.IReference`1<Double>
```

It works without issues when running without .net native in debug mode.
I tried to add the following runtime directive to prevent it being stripped, but without success:

```
<Type Name="Windows.Foundation.IReference{Double}" Dynamic="Required All" />
```

My Min and target version are:
[image]

Comment: I viewed a similar case that throw `Windows.Foundation.IReference1<Double>` error. and that project builds with uno command. Are they the same?

Comment: The only touching point with uno I have is a dependeny via liveCharts2 that references `SkiaSharp.Views.Uno`

Comment: Well, it looks same problem, the better way is post this problem in  SkiaSharp.Views.Uno issue box [here](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues).

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I reverted back to the when I started using LiveCharts and the issue was actually introduced there. But I'm not sure if it is actually an issue with SkiaSharp since I used a charting library on that base before. So I think I contact the LiveChart Team first. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Ok, good, if you have any result please feel free post below.